# Is there a limit to squares pushed?

Tags: dnd-4e, forced-movement

I remember one of the few times I played 4E D&D, I was a Con'lock specialising in pushing, and a few other character also had a lot of ranged push abilities. We ended up pushing the big bad so far away (14+ squares) it couldn't attack, then the avenger managed to convert the pushed squares into damage (I forget the power/item/thing used).

Is there a maximum range allowed on push per turn? Should there be? What we did seems excessive.

Comment: The only limit I know of is the "map".  I know some DMs would not allow you to push mobs off "the map" and they just hang at the last square. But I doubt that is an official rule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no overall limit on how far you can push someone.

Bear in mind that you could have used other powers dealing more damage or imposing status effects instead, and your attack powers aren't guaranteed to hit, so it's fair what you did.

Find out what your avenger used, and check that it works on forced movement, and on forced movement imposed by his allies. Some powers only damage an enemy when he moves willingly.

Comment: Looking round, I think it's the thunderwave staff, and it was an invoker, not avenger.

Comment: @Pureferret The Thunderwave staff isn't so powerful. It's a Daily power and it only changes one of the user's own push into d6s of damage, instead of the push.